# Partial specialization of a class template member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have defined two class templates, `class two_val` and `class trait_vector` as follows:

```
template<class T>
class two_val{
    private:
        T first_val;
        T second_val;
               
    public:

        two_val() :
            first_val {},
            second_val {}
        {}
        
        T get_first() const {return first_val;}
};
```

and:

```
template<class T>
class trait_vector{
    private:
    
        std::vector<T> vec;
                
    public:
        trait_vector() :
            vec {}
        {}
};
```

Now, for the case that I have a `trait_vector` of `two_val<T>`s of any class `T`, I would like to provide a function that returns me the `trait_vector<T>` of the respective `first_val`s.

I managed to implement this by specializing the class `trait_vector` as follows:

```
template<class T>
class trait_vector<two_val<T>>{
    private: 
        std::vector<two_val<T>> vec;
                
    public:
        trait_vector() :
            vec {}
        {}
        
        trait_vector<T> get_first() {
            trait_vector<double> result {};
            for(unsigned i=0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
                result.vec.push_back(vec[i].get_first());
            }
            return result;

        }
};
```

But I would like to avoid copy and pasting the entire rest of the class. It feels like there should be a shorter solution (especially since the classes I'm actually working with are much bigger).

However, every direct solution that I tried ran into the problem that function templates cannot be partially specialized.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25099179/21611679) explains how to use a helper class for the desired function in a related case. However, I did not manage the transfer to my situation.

Comment: Does it actually need to be a member function? Could it just be a global function instead?

Comment: The objective is to provide an additional function that will be available only for a particular specialization of trait_vector. The title of the question could be changed to indicate this more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a trait `is_two_val`:

```
template <typename T> struct is_two_val : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_two_val<two_val<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

Having `typedef` in your two_val class might help (else might be done with externl traits)

```
template<class T>
class two_val{
public:
    using type = T;
// ...
};
```

then you might SFINAE or `requires` (C++20) for your member with that traits:

```
template<class T>
class trait_vector{
private: 
    std::vector<T> vec;
                
public:
    trait_vector() : vec {} {}
        
    auto get_first() requires (is_two_val<T>::value)
    {
        trait_vector<typename T::type> result{};
        result.reserve(vec.size());
        for(const auto& p : vec){
            result.vec.push_back(p.get_first());
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I made my code work with your suggestion and everything seems fine! In the definition of the trait `is_two_val` it has to be `template<class T>` instead of `template<T>`, right?

Comment: Indeed, typo fixed.

Comment: Now I still ran into a problem. As long as I actually only defined variables of type  `trait_vector<two_val<T>>` for some `T` everything worked indeed fine. But now I tried to declare a variable of type `trait_vector<double>` and the compiler (g++ 12.2.0) complained "error: ‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type". Something still seems to be wrong around the `requires` syntax.

Comment: Need to change return type to `auto`. `T::type` is indeed invalid for `T=double` in a place where T is fixed (it is a template of the class, not of the member function).

Comment: Thanks again, I think now it all works out. May I interest you in my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76147846/21611679)?