# Lifting member functions from a class template to a second class template over the first one

Tags: c++, c++20, class-template, lifting

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76129953/21611679).

There, thanks to the answer of [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42), I managed to lift the member function `get_first()`of a class template `two_val<T>` to all classes of the form `trait_vector<two_val<T>>`. See the code block below in order to see what these classes are and how the member function lift was achieved.

```
template<class T>
class two_val{
    private:   
        T first_val;
        T second_val;
               
    public:
        using type = T;

        two_val() :
            first_val {},
            second_val {}
        {}

        T get_first(){return first_val;}        
};

template <typename T> struct is_two_val : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_two_val<two_val<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
class trait_vector{
private: 
    std::vector<T> vec;
                
public:
    trait_vector() : vec {} {}
        
    auto get_first() requires (is_two_val<T>::value)
    {
        trait_vector<typename T::type> result{};
        result.reserve(vec.size());
        for(const auto& p : vec){
            result.vec.push_back(p.get_first());
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

This all works well and is very nice.

But now I want to define further member functions of `two_val<T>`, like `T get_second()`, `T add_first_and_second()`, `bool check_equality_of_first_and_second()`, etc. For all these I would like to have corresponding lifted member functions for classes of the form `trait_vector<two_val<T>>`. However, what I would like to avoid is to copy and paste the definition of `trait_vector<two_val<T>>::get_first()` over and over again.

So what I'm aiming at is some member template function `lift_from_two_val` of class `trait_vector` that takes a member function of `two_val<T>` with return type `U` and turns it into a member function of `trait_vector<two_val<T>>` with return type `trait_vector<U>`. Then the lifts of the individual member functions of `two_val<T>` could be defined as one-liners by simply applying `lift_from_two_val` to the respective functions.

But I'm still too unfamiliar with the syntax of C++ to be sure if this is possible, let alone to actually make it work.

In case all of this is actually possible as I envision it: What if I want to lift from a bunch of other (template) classes to `trait_vector`? Would there again be a way around copy and pasting the code from `lift_from_two_val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<std::invocable<T const> F>
auto lift(F f) 
{
    using RT = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>;
    trait_vector<RT> result{};
    result.reserve(vec.size());
    for(const auto& p : vec){
        result.vec.push_back(std::invoke(f, p));
    }
    return result;
}
```

now you can do this

```
trait_vector<two_val<int>> bob;
trait_vector<int> alice = bob.lift(&two_val<int>::get_first);
trait_vector<int> eve = bob.lift(&two_val<int>::get_second);
```

etc.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/znPK5cE6a).

Comment: Awesome! This is precisely what I was hoping for!

Comment: @ManuelDu You might want to `std::decay_t` the `RT` btw.

Comment: I might... but first I will have to invest some time to understand what that means.

Comment: @ManuelDu if your function returns a reference, vectors can't hold it.  `decay_t` removes references and const and converts arrays to pointers and functions to function pointers; the return value is more likely to be storable in a `vector` or the like.